# Putting values into a struct from a file

Tags: c, struct

Okay so I know how to put values into a struct from a file.

My values in the file are seperated my commas. The data is like this:

```
number, product, price, other
```

**Only some items have the other value!**

How do I have an optional value in a struct?

**such:**

```
typedef struct stockItem {
    int number;
    char* product;
    int price;
    char *other;
} stockItem;
```

**I'm inputting the data something like this:**

```
while (fgets(str, 255, invf) != NULL){   
    int numOfItems = atoi(strtok(str, " ,"));
    char *stockCode = strtok(NULL, " ,");
    int price = atoi(strtok(NULL, " ,"));
    char *other = strTok(NULL, " "));

    stockItem *item = stockItem_new(numOfItems , stockCode, price, other);
```

It of course doesn't execute because some items have the other, what should i do? should i insert null into every value that doesn't have an other ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should set `other` to `NULL` for every item that doesn't have that field. This is the normal way to indicate the absence of something pointed to.

Also, `strtok()` will return an internal pointer to `str`, which you reuse for every item. You should ensure that your `stockItem_new()` function is actually copying that data (using `strdup()` or `strcpy()`) and not just setting that field equal to the pointer, or this field in all your `struct`s will end up pointing to the same memory, which will change each time you call `fgets()`, and will probably cease to exist altogether after your reading function returns.

Here's some sample code:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 256

struct stock_item {
    int number;
    char * product;
    int price;
    char * other;
};

struct stock_item * stock_item_new(const int num_items,
                                   const char * stock_code,
                                   const int price,
                                   const char * other);
void stock_item_destroy(struct stock_item * item);
void stock_item_print(struct stock_item * item);

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if ( !fp ) {
        perror("couldn't open data file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    const char * delim = " ,\n";
    while ( fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) ) {
        int num_items = atoi(strtok(buffer, delim));
        char * stock_code = strtok(NULL, delim);
        int price = atoi(strtok(NULL, delim));
        char * other = strtok(NULL, delim);

        struct stock_item * new_item;
        new_item = stock_item_new(num_items, stock_code, price, other);

        stock_item_print(new_item);

        stock_item_destroy(new_item);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

struct stock_item * stock_item_new(const int num_items,
                                   const char * stock_code,
                                   const int price,
                                   const char * other)
{
    struct stock_item * new_item = malloc(sizeof *new_item);
    if ( !new_item ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory for stock item");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_item->number = num_items;
    new_item->price = price;

    new_item->product = strdup(stock_code);
    if ( !new_item->product ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory for product name");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( other ) {
        new_item->other = strdup(other);
        if ( !new_item->other ) {
            perror("couldn't allocate memory for 'other' field");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else {
        new_item->other = NULL;
    }

    return new_item;
}

void stock_item_destroy(struct stock_item * item)
{
    free(item->product);
    free(item->other);
    free(item);
}

void stock_item_print(struct stock_item * item)
{
    printf("%d, %s, %d, %s\n", item->number, item->product,
            item->price, item->other ? item->other : "(none)");
}
```

which, when run with the following data file:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox/itemfile$ cat data.txt
20, rifle, 99
33, bucket, 30, plastic
50, fish, 5, gold
12, hammer, 45, left-handed
9, backscratcher, 13
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox/itemfile$
```

produces the following output:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox/itemfile$ ./itemfile
20, rifle, 99, (none)
33, bucket, 30, plastic
50, fish, 5, gold
12, hammer, 45, left-handed
9, backscratcher, 13, (none)
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox/itemfile$
```

The `stock_item_print()` function checks whether the `other` field is `NULL`, and if it is, outputs `"(none)"`. Otherwise it prints it normally.

Also note that passing `NULL` to `free()` is fine, so we don't have to check the `other` field in the `stock_item_destroy()` function.

Finally, I haven't made any changes to it (other than adding `'\n'` to the list of delimiters), but your parsing code with `strtok()` is very fragile, and should be expanded to include a great deal more error checking. For instance, `strtol()` is better than `atoi()`, and you should be checking each time whether `strtok()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: I have ensured I have used strdup within the stockItem_new(), so within my struct would I change the values to NULL or would I do it in the loop?

Comment: Easiest is to do it in the loop. Then `stockItem_new()` can check whether the value of `other` that was passed to it is `NULL`. If it is, it can just set that field to `NULL`. If it's not, then it can copy it, just like with `stockCode`.

Comment: so if I were to do it in the loop would I have to set it to NULL after each loop otherwise would the value not carry on ?

Comment: @Blarsssss: Give me a moment, I'll write some code out.